Is there a way to tell the GEKKO solver to start from a non-zero value
I am trying to implement real-time MPC in gekko. This means that I need this simulation to run in real time indefinitely. Something similar to do-MPC's real-time MPC. The general code loop is calling the solver at every time step to re-evaluate the problem based on current states and then shift the m.time array by 1 (i.e. if it started as [0-20] the next time step will be [1-21] etc.).
The problem arises when I define my m.time array like this:
m.time = np.linspace(current_time, current_time+prediction_horizon, prediction_horizon+1) current_time += 1
It should have the desired effect. Instead, the solver gives me this warning message:
Warning: shifting time horizon to start at zero Current starting time value:  18.
Which means that now the simulation window does not shift. Is this just a limitation of the solver or is this something I can change?
I have tried extending the time horizon dynamically which has worked:
m.time = np.linspace(0, current_time+prediction_horizon, prediction_horizon+1) current_time += 1
Which means I need to append new values to all my arrays so that the arrays for all the solving parameters are the same length. However, this significantly slows down the computaion time 60 seconds in. Shifting a set horizon would overcome this but I can't seem to achieve it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

The MPC application time horizon is relative to the start time of zero. Time is not typically in the model so it shouldn't need to start from a non-zero value. Gekko automatically time shifts the prior solution and accepts updates to any disturbances, setpoints, state variable initial conditions, and measurement feedback to create a new MPC solution. Below is a simple application that demonstrates the approach.

import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# Initialize the GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, 20, 21)  # Time grid
mass = 500
b = m.Param(value=50)
K = m.Param(value=0.8)
p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)  # Manipulated Variable (gas pedal)
v = m.CV(value=0)  # Controlled Variable (velocity)

# Define the dynamic equation
m.Equation(mass * v.dt() == -v * b + K * b * p)

# Set optimization mode for control
m.options.IMODE = 6  # Control mode

# Tuning parameters for MV (gas pedal)
p.STATUS = 1  # Allow optimizer to change
p.FSTATUS = 0
p.DCOST = 0.1  # Smooth out gas pedal movement
p.DMAX = 20  # Limit rate of change

# Tuning parameters for CV (velocity)
v.STATUS = 1  # Include set point in the objective
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2  # L2 norm
v.SP = 40  # Set point for velocity
v.TR_INIT = 1  # Enable set point trajectory
v.TAU = 5  # Time constant of trajectory

# List to store frames for GIF
frames = []

# Run the optimization in a loop and save plots
for i in range(25):
    if i==15:
        v.SP = 20
    
    print(f'MPC cycle: {i} of 25')
    m.solve(disp=False)  # Solve the optimization problem

    # Create a plot for each iteration
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 8))
    
    ax1.plot(m.time+i, p.value, 'b-', lw=2)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Gas Pedal (%)')
    ax1.set_title(f'MPC Cycle {i+1}')
    ax1.set_ylim([0,100])

    ax2.plot(m.time+i, v.value, 'r--', lw=2)
    ax2.plot(m.time+i,np.ones_like(m.time)*v.SP,'k:',lw=2)
    ax2.set_ylim([0,50])
    ax2.set_ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    fig.tight_layout()

    # Save the plot as an image frame
    fig.canvas.draw()
    frame = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
    frame = frame.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
    frames.append(Image.fromarray(frame))

    plt.close(fig)  # Close the figure to save memory

# Save the frames as a GIF
frames[0].save('control_simulation.gif', format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=500, loop=0)

print("GIF saved as 'control_simulation.gif'")

I included m.time+i for the plot to show the progression in time.
ax2.plot(m.time+i, v.value, 'r--', lw=2)

This same progression isn't needed for the Gekko application and can be added after the solution is completed to any visualizations.
